# Python and Opswat

Tags: python, windows

I need to trigger my AntiVirus (McAfee) when accessing a test-virus URL (http://eicar.org/download/eicar.com) via python. If I use IE, Firefox or even wget for windows, the AntiVirus detects that a virus URL was accessed, which is the expected behavior. However, when using urllib or urllib2, the virus URL is successfully accessed and the AntiVirus does not detect that a "bad" URL has been reached.
Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: did you try writing the output to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the output to disk- the virus scanner will see it then.